# Dynamic Naming textfield in MUI data Grid

Tags: reactjs, mui-x-data-grid

I am using MUI data grid and first columns values (Asset description) comes from an array and the headers Meember1, Member2 and... also comes from an array, I need to enter a specific values into each fields to insert record into DB using using react-redux. I need different names for all cells which are associated with member and assets shown in below image pasted.
[image: assetinforamtion]

### Now, my question is how to generate dynamic names for each cells based on column and row which u see in the above image? thanks for your help.

Here is my code for both columns and rows.

```
const membersName = ["Member1", "Member2", "Member3"]; 
const assetTypes = [
    { id: 1, assetTitle: "Cash", assetType: "cash" },
    { id: 2, assetTitle: "Checking Accounts", assetType: "checkAccount" },
    { id: 3, assetTitle: "Other", assetType: "other" },
  ];
```

// columns for currency values

```
const assetFileds = membersName.map((items, index) => {
    const name = "cash" + index;
    const newObject = {
      field: "member_" + index,
      headerName: items,
      flex: 1.0,
      disableClickEventBubbling: true,
      sortable: false,
      disableColumnMenu: true,
      renderCell: (params) => (
        <>
          <CurrencyValue
            fullWidth={false}
            // defaultValue={params.row.description}
            variant="standard"
            name={name}
            value={values.name}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
          <BackupIcon
            onClick={doOpenModal}
            visibility={!values.name ? "hidden" : "visible"}
          />
        </>
      ),
    };
    return newObject;
  });

const columnForAssetTypes = {
    field: "assetTitle",
    headerName: "Asset Description",
    flex: 1.0,
    disableClickEventBubbling: true,
    sortable: false,
    disableColumnMenu: true,
  };

  //render final columns
  const renderColumns = (array, index, newItem) => {
    return [...array.slice(0, index), newItem, ...array.slice(index)];
  };
  const finalColumns = renderColumns(assetFileds, 0, columnForAssetTypes);
  //set columns and rows
  //const columns = columnsOld;
  const columns = finalColumns;
  const rows = assetTypes;



 return (
    <Container>
      <div className="about-yourself">
        <Grid container spacing={3}>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <div className="about-header d-flex">
              <span className="icon-w-bg-l">
                <img src={ChildCareProviderImage} alt="App user" />
              </span>
              <h3> Asset information</h3>
            </div>
            <div style={{ height: 400, width: "100%" }}>
              <DataGrid
                rows={rows}
                columns={columns}
                pageSize={5}
                rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
                //disableSelectionOnClick
              />
            </div>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </div>
 </Container>
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the rows to below  and now gets different name for all cells in the grid:

```
const rows = assetTypes.map((item, index) => {
        const initialObj = {
          id: index + 1,
          assetTitle: item.assetTitle,
          assetType: item.asstType,
        };
        return membersName.reduce((a, b) => {
          return {
            ...a,
            [b]: null,
          };
        }, initialObj);
      });
```